# Reason to define two-way relationships in Sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

In the Sequelize association documentation ([link](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/)), in the example where we have one team that can have many players, the following relationship modeling is defined:

```
Team.hasMany(Player);
Player.belongsTo(Team);
```

I have attempted myself and saw that having only EITHER statement would've worked. Is there a reason why we might need both at the same time? One reason I can think of is doing `belongsTo` sets the on delete mechanism to cascade. But I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: When you need to query from Team(eg: `Team.findAll({ include: Player })`), you need `Team.hasMany(Player)`. When you need to query from Player(eg: `Player.findAll({ include: Team })`), you need `Player.belongsTo(Team)`.  So, if you only query from either side, you need 1 association.

Comment: Ahh got it. Do you happen to know if Sequelize internally creates an index on the FKs? Or simply making the findAll functions available to the model(s) with the association declared?

Comment: If you are creating the table as new meaning you don't have this table in your DB yet, it should create FK connections.   However, FK connections are not necessary for `findAll` to have `include` option.  `findAll` with `include` works fine regardless of absence of the FK connections.